# Compatibility between SFP+ and SFP28 ports at 1gbps

Tags: sfp

I own a HP DL380 Gen10 with a HPE Ethernet 10/25Gb 2-port 640SFP28 (817753-B21) network card. The thing is that now I need 1gbps RJ45 connectors and those are not (strangely) present in the server. There seems to be no SFP+ adapters including RJ45 connectors (at least not listed at HP docs).

My question is regarding compatibility, in general:

- Can I use non-HP SFP+ with this server?
- Can I use SFP transceivers on a SFP28 connector? I understand I can use SFP on SFP+ ports and SFP+ connectors on SFP28 ports so I would suppose this would be also true for SFP-SFP28 but something tells me don't do it.

What are you experiences with this issue? SFP* are way cheaper than purchasing a new PCIe network card.

Thanks in advance,
Jose

Comment: SFP modules generally work in SFP+ slots, you might need to force speed etc. Also HP might be picky, the easiest is to test, modules are quite cheap.

Answer (score 1):

That NIC is called *HPE Ethernet **10/25Gb** 2-port 640SFP28*, indicating that it is compatible with 10G and 25G Ethernet. It is *not* compatible with 1G Ethernet, however. The NIC is also not compatible with any twisted-pair transceiver, only fiber or DAC - check the [specs](https://www.hpe.com/psnow/doc/c04849446).

If you require a 1000BASE-T port you'll need to add a compatible NIC.